# Are there any specific recommended timings to read Quran in Ramadan?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

I heard that the best time to read the Quran is after Fajir prayer, is that true? Does that apply to Ramadan too? What is/are the recommanded timings to read the Quran during Ramadan?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No you can read the  quran any time you want not only in ramadan even in normal days it's up to you when you want to read except the time of (zawal) it means from 11:45 am to approximately 12:40 pm or 1:00 pm no one knows the perfect time but majority tells that time as I mentioned above you can't read the quran in the time of  zawal because the sun is right on the above of the earth and it is forbidden to read the quran in the time of zawal but the time duration is depend on in which country you live what is  your region so it is better for you to ask a imaam of your area I hope it will help

Comment: Can you please give me sources or hadiths of Jawal being a bad time to read Quran? Thanks.